# How should be the architecture of the object in C# if there are few properties and out of those only one be used at a time?

Tags: c#

I have classes like below:

```
public class APIAuth
{
    public ServiceAuthenticationMethod AuthenticationMethod { get; set; }

    public BasicAuthentication BasicAuth { get; set; }

    public SigV4Authentication SigV4Auth { get; set; }
    
    public JwtAuth { get; set; }

 }


public enum ServiceAuthenticationMethod
{
    Anonymous = 1,
    BasicAuthentication = 2,
    SigV4 = 3,
    Jwt = 4,
}

 public class BasicAuthentication
 {
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
 }

 public class SigV4Authentication
 {
    public string AccessKey { get; set; }

    public string SecretKey { get; set; }

    public string Region { get; set; }

    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    public string SessionToken { get; set; }
 }

 public class JwtAuthentication
 {
    public string Token{ get; set; }
 }
```

Now, based on the `AuthenticationMethod` property of the `APIAuth` class, one of the properties will be having value and the others will be null. For e.g., if `AuthenticationMethod` has `BasicAuthentication` as a value, then the `BasicAuth` property of the `APIAuth` class will be having value and `SigV4Auth` and `JwtAuth` would be null. And when storing the data in the database, either of the Auth property will be serialized and stored depending upon the `AuthenticationMethod` value.

So is there any way to create a class so that there would be only one property called `AuthenticationType` and it would be having value based on the `AuthenticationMethod`? So that, when storing in the database, I can simply serialize the `AuthenticationType` value and when deserializing back I can specify the type as `AuthenticationType`.

Not sure if it is possible or not but I am open to suggestions of having a better approach.

Comment: `class APIAuth<T> { T AuthenticationType { get; set; } }`?

Comment: Personally, I'd create a common interface that the individual authentication types then implement, but I'd only do that in the domain layer of the application, in the repository layer I'd leave it as it is and then only map the actually used authentication to the `Authentication` property depending on the `AuthenticationMethod`